# Yii2 - QueryAll is having issue

Tags: yii2

I am using Query Builder with multiple where clause. When I use this query,

```
            $query1 = new \yii\db\Query();
        $query1->select('*')
            ->from('assessment_score ca')
            ->where(['AND','ca.is_status' => 0, 'ca.assessment_type' => 'CONTINUOUS ASSESSMENT', 'ca.ca_type' => 'CONTINUOUS ASSESSMENT'])
            ->andFilterWhere(['ca.state_office_id' => $model->report_state_office_id])
            ->andFilterWhere(['ca.study_centre_id' => $model->report_study_centre_id])
            ->andFilterWhere(['ca.programme_id' => $model->report_programme_id])
            ->andFilterWhere(['ca.department_id' => $model->report_department_id])
            ->andFilterWhere(['ca.academic_level_id' => $model->report_academic_level_id])
            ->andFilterWhere(['ca.academic_year_id' => $model->report_academic_year_id])
            ->andFilterWhere(['ca.academic_semester_id' => $model->report_academic_semester_id])
            ->andFilterWhere(['ca.course_id' => $model->report_course_id]);

        $command=$query1->createCommand();
        $ca_data=$command->queryAll();
```

**I got this error**

[image: Query Error]

Then, when I changed the code to this, no response:

```
            $selected_list = $_POST['ca'];

        $query1 = new \yii\db\Query();
        $query1->select('*')
            ->from('assessment_score ca')
            ->where(['ca.is_status' => 0])
            ->andWhere(['ca.assessment_type' => 'CONTINUOUS ASSESSMENT'])
            ->andWhere(['ca.ca_type' => 'CONTINUOUS ASSESSMENT'])
            ->andFilterWhere(['ca.state_office_id' => $model->report_state_office_id])
            ->andFilterWhere(['ca.study_centre_id' => $model->report_study_centre_id])
            ->andFilterWhere(['ca.programme_id' => $model->report_programme_id])
            ->andFilterWhere(['ca.department_id' => $model->report_department_id])
            ->andFilterWhere(['ca.academic_level_id' => $model->report_academic_level_id])
            ->andFilterWhere(['ca.academic_year_id' => $model->report_academic_year_id])
            ->andFilterWhere(['ca.academic_semester_id' => $model->report_academic_semester_id])
            ->andFilterWhere(['ca.course_id' => $model->report_course_id]);

        $command=$query1->createCommand();
        $ca_data=$command->queryAll();
```

How do I re-write the code appropriately to solve the issue of multiple where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to change the query format for the `where()` statement as you need to provide every condition (name=>value pair) as a separate array rather than just `name=>value` pairs, you currently have

```
->where(['AND', 'ca.is_status' => 0, 'ca.assessment_type' => 'CONTINUOUS ASSESSMENT', 'ca.ca_type' => 'CONTINUOUS ASSESSMENT'])
```

which will create the query like below if no other parameter is provided for `andFilterWhere()` statements.

```
SELECT * FROM `assessment_score` `ca` 
WHERE (0) 
AND (CONTINUOUS ASSESSMENT) AND (CONTINUOUS ASSESSMENT)
```

which is incorrect and throwing the error, you can notice that in your Exception image, so change it to the one below

```
->where(['AND',
       ['ca.is_status' => 0],
       ['ca.assessment_type' => 'CONTINUOUS ASSESSMENT'],
       ['ca.ca_type' => 'CONTINUOUS ASSESSMENT']
])
```

which will output the query like

```
SELECT * FROM `assessment_score` `ca` 
WHERE (`ca`.`is_status`=0) 
    AND (`ca`.`assessment_type`='CONTINUOUS ASSESSMENT') 
    AND (`ca`.`ca_type`='CONTINUOUS ASSESSMENT')
```

Your complete query should look like this

```
$query1 = new \yii\db\Query();
$query1->select('*')
        ->from('assessment_score ca')
        ->where(['AND',
            ['ca.is_status' => 0],
            ['ca.assessment_type' => 'CONTINUOUS ASSESSMENT'],
            ['ca.ca_type' => 'CONTINUOUS ASSESSMENT']
        ])
        ->andFilterWhere(['ca.state_office_id' => $model->report_state_office_id])
        ->andFilterWhere(['ca.study_centre_id' => $model->report_study_centre_id])
        ->andFilterWhere(['ca.programme_id' => $model->report_programme_id])
        ->andFilterWhere(['ca.department_id' => $model->report_department_id])
        ->andFilterWhere(['ca.academic_level_id' => $model->report_academic_level_id])
        ->andFilterWhere(['ca.academic_year_id' => $model->report_academic_year_id])
        ->andFilterWhere(['ca.academic_semester_id' => $model->report_academic_semester_id])
        ->andFilterWhere(['ca.course_id' => $model->report_course_id]);

$command = $query1->createCommand();
$ca_data = $command->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

based on yii2 guide for Operator Format

> Operator format allows you to specify arbitrary conditions in a
>   programmatic way. It takes the following format:
>
> [operator, operand1, operand2, ...] where the operands can each be
>   specified in string format, hash format or operator format
>   recursively, while the operator can be one of the following:
>
> and: the operands should be concatenated together using AND. For
>   example, ['and', 'id=1', 'id=2']

so in your case should be

```
->where(['AND', 'ca.is_status = 0',
   "ca.assessment_type = 'CONTINUOUS ASSESSMENT'",
         "ca.ca_type  = 'CONTINUOUS ASSESSMENT'"])
```

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder#operator-format

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to remove `AND` from array passed to `where()`:

```
->where([
    'ca.is_status' => 0, 
    'ca.assessment_type' => 'CONTINUOUS ASSESSMENT', 
    'ca.ca_type' => 'CONTINUOUS ASSESSMENT'
])
```

If you pass associative array, it will be treated as pairs of column-value for conditions for `WHERE` in query. If you pass `AND` as first element, it is no longer a associative array, and query builder will ignore keys and only combine values as complete condition.